# How does XSLT processor find matching templates?

Tags: xml, xslt

For example, consider the following XML:

```
<root>
    <level1>
        <!--S-->
        <level2>bingo!</level2>
    </level1>
</root>
```

And assume we have two templates: `match="level2"` and `match="level1/level2"`.

When parser reaches the `level2` node, how exactly does it determine that current node is matched by **both** templates, and that it must choose second template because it is more specific? What is formal definition of a "more specific" template?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1531664/583513

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#conflict

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with FiveO that this is a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531664/583513), but then again, you also ask specification what the difference is between `foo` and `bar/foo` and which one is selected.

Essentially, unless you specify a priority on the `xsl:template` declaration, the order in which things are matched is determined by the rules in [5.5 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#conflict) for XSLT 1.0, [6.4 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#conflict) for XSLT 2.0 and [6.4 Conflict Resolution for Template Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#conflict). These are the *formal definitions* you asked for.

However, the basic rule is quite simple: the more specific a match, the higher the priority. Except that there is no difference in priority between multiple predicates or deeper paths.

If two templates match that have the same priority, in XSLT 1.0 and 2.0 the processor can either recover (take the last one in declaration order) or signal the error. In 3.0 you can set this behavior declarative with `<xsl:mode on-multiple-match="xxx" />`.

A NodeTest (which is your `match="level2"`) gets default priority `-0.5` and if it has a child axis specifier (which is your `match="level1/level2"`) it gets default priority `0`. Higher priority goes first, which is why `bar/foo` will match `foo`, provided it has a parent `bar`. Otherwise it will match `foo`.

The basics of these rules have not changed between XSLT versions, they have just been expanded to allow specification of new allowed syntax.

More information is in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1531664/583513).

**Update, based on comment:**
You ask how this is implemented. I can only speak for [our XSLT 3.0 processor, Exselt](http://exselt.net), and explain it in general lines, because the actual process is rather involved because of many subtleties and optimizations.

- Processing starts with the initial context node with the initial mode
- Processor keeps a hash of all modes and splits all unions into separate matching templates
- Each mode has a list of patterns that are ordered by priority
- Upon visiting a node (here the initial context node), the processor goes over all patterns and finds the first that matches
- It does this by compare the path backwards (similar to how it is explained in the spec), as follows:
  ** The path to a node is known as an annotation
  ** The rightmost child axis step is taken and matched to the current node based on its `NameTest` or `KindTest` (see productions of these in the XPath spec)
  ** Only if it matches, the next (to the left) child axis step is matched, and so on
  ** If the full path matches, the predicate, if any is evaluated against the current node, this is done later, because it is a more involved process and may require the processor to move away from the current node, which is relatively costly.
- If all matches, the matched template is executed with the current node set to the context node of the template.

Comment: BTW, the same principle applies to CSS match expressions. The more specific rule wins, out of multiple rules with the same specificity the one declared last wins.

Comment: My question was not about how the priority is determined after a set of matches had been found, but rather about how these very matches are made. I mean, we have a current node (context), and we have a set of template rules - how do we (XSLT processor) filter them to produce a set of matching rules?

Comment: @DmitryArestov: I updated it. There are actually complete papers written about this, it is very hard to explain it in the brief context of this forum, but hopefully you'll get the general idea.