# How are XSL templates applied?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this xml:

```
<temas>
  <tema>
    <titulo>Odio como a un burgués la fuga de las sábanas.</titulo>
    <nav>
    <menu>
      <menu-item>One</menu-item>
      <menu-item>Two </menu-item>
      <menu-item>Three</menu-item>
      </menu>
    </nav>
    <content>
      <span>hi</span>
      <span>hi</span>
  </content>
  <pie>
    <prev>something</prev>
    </pie>
  </tema>
</temas>
```

To which I have applied this XSL transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="content">
  <xsl:copy-of select="./*" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="span" priority="10000">
    Why I don't show up?!
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In my limited knowledge of XSLT, I would have expected that the last template would replace the `span` nodes, but that doesn't happen. I hoped that the identity transform would copy everything and apply all the templates that matched, but it fails to apply that last template. I tried to change the priority to no avail.

Can you explain how XSL works in this cases when applying multiple templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would have expected that the last template would replace the span
>   nodes, but that doesn't happen.

It doesn't happen because the last template is never applied. It isn't applied because the template matching the parent `content` node does not apply templates. You would see a different result if instead of:

```
<xsl:template match="content">
  <xsl:copy-of select="./*" />
</xsl:template>
```

you would do:

```
<xsl:template match="content">
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>
```

See a more detailed explanation here:
[Why does processing a parent element's template prevent the processing of child element templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901003/why-does-processing-a-parent-elements-template-prevent-the-processing-of-child/28906302#28906302)